# Robot Framework - Appium Do Not See Java_Home

Tags: android, automated-tests, robotframework, appium-android, java-home

first time When I do all the settings and i run appium-doctor it passes, but next time I restart my macbook and run again.I received these message error not see

My Error :

`WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖  ANDROID_HOME is NOT set!

WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ JAVA_HOME is NOT set!

WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ adb could not be found because ANDROID_HOME is NOT set!

WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ android could not be found because ANDROID_HOME is NOT set!

WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ emulator could not be found because ANDROID_HOME is NOT set`

I don't know why it is like this.
Please help me fix it  T____________T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your shell profile cant read ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME on a fresh start.
You have 2 options,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/user_name/Android/Sdk
```

Either use the export command on each shell opening

OR

add ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME to your profile, which depends on your profile. 
each shell has its own RC file, like `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`.

Recommending the second one